# How to tell Excel to change right encoding in opened file?

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, encoding

Can somebody tell me please how to tell Excel to set up right encoding for csv file? It seems it is not possible without any annoying steps. I would like to see something like Libre office or Open office which open dialog where program ask me for encoding for the file. Is there something similar in excel or is it possible to set up encoding for already opened file? Thank you.

Comment: Do not **OPEN** the file. Rather **IMPORT** the file using Power Query or the Legacy Wizard. You can set the encoding at that time. If you **OPEN** the file, you won't be able to change the encoding afterwards.

Comment: But it is really useless. I know that I can import the file, but I think there should be a better way. How is that possible that Libre office and Open Office can do it, but Excel not. They never open file which was saved in another encoding?

Comment: You would need to direct your question of "why" toward the developers. Are you saying it is useless to expect someone to remember to click on a different button than Open depending on the type of file they might be opening? If that is the case, you can always add a button that triggers a macro that makes that decision for you.

Comment: The fault belongs to how the CSV file was created. If it had started with a [Byte order mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), everything would have been automatic.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I mean situation when I click on file in File explorer. Dont want to open Excel first. Thats the point.

Comment: @harrymc This looks like a solution. I need to try it. Thnak you. Make an answer. Hope it will work.

Comment: There is nothing you can change in Excel to alter that behavior.  You can change the behavior of windows as to what happens when you click on a csv file in Explorer. You can change the nature of the CSV file. (*Using a BOM might work depending on the type of encoding you are dealing with*). You could use Power Automate to convert the CSV files to XLSX files, but I don't have experience with that tool. Good luck! and please post back with your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Excel or any other Office application opens a file with the wrong
encoding, this usually means that the file lacks
[Byte order mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

The BOM is a header of a few bytes that specified whether the encoding
is UTF-8, UTF-16 or UTF-32, or others.

If this CSV file can be created with a BOM, its correct handling by
Office will then be automatic.